# Restrict function access ONLY to one other specific contract in Solidity

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, ether

I have a security problem in my Solidity contracts and I can't figure out how to fix it.

The flow goes like this:

- First, we create an instance of contract A;
- Create an instance of contract B, which receives the contract A instance in the constructor (its address);
- At some point, contract B calls a function 'foo' from contract A which tells contract A to send money to an address (the address is received as a parameter);
- Contract A sees the msg.sender as the address of contract B;

My problem is:

- I want to restrict the access for the function 'foo' in contract B only to be called by contract A (no calls made by humans manually);
- I cannot make a modifier to check the address. Since I create Contract A before Contract B, I cannot know the address of Contract B in Contract A;
- I cannot make the function internal as the contracts are not derived;

Can you please offer me advice on how to fix this problem or explain another approach on this? I am new to Solidity.
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I cannot make a modifier to check the address.*

You can, but the address needs to be in a variable, set after the contract B has been deployed.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract ContractA {
    address contractB;
    
    modifier onlyContractB {
        require(msg.sender == contractB);
        _;
    }

    function foo() external onlyContractB {
    }
    
    function setContractBAddress(address _contractB) external {
        contractB = _contractB;
    }
}
```

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

interface IContractA {
    function foo() external;
}

contract ContractB {
    IContractA contractA;
    
    constructor(address _contractA) {
        contractA = IContractA(_contractA);
    }

    function callFoo() external {
        contractA.foo();
    }

}
```

1. Deploy contract A
2. Deploy contract B, passing it the "A" address in the constructor
3. Set the `contractB` value in "Contract A".

I left out any auth mechanism while setting the `contractB` address in `ContractA` for simplicity. In this example, anyone can set the address, which you probably don't want, and you should add a mechanism allowing only authorized senders to set the `contractB` value in `ContractA`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer!
From what I understand, after the creation of Contract A and Contract B, someone (most probably only the owner of contract A) should manually call the setContractBAddress function, right?

Comment: @Flendor exactly